# Add Junit Testing in Android Studio(Imported project from Eclipse)

Tags: java, android, junit, android-studio

Recently I tried to migrate my Eclipse project to Android Studio .

But while doing that i figured out that the project structure(default Android Studio created project) is  different if our project is migrated from Eclipse.

Like, for a new created project in Android Studio, the sourceSets part of the `build.gradle` file :

```
sourceSets {
  main.java.srcDirs = ['src/java']
main.resources.srcDirs = ['src/resources']
}

   For a migrated project from Eclipse, the sourceSets part of the build.gradle file must be that :

android {
sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }

    instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
  }
}
```

Problem:

Since I dont have any "tests" folder in my project, I tried to create a folder

Testing folder structure is

```
  "AppName/tests/TestAppName/src/FirstTest.java"
```

After creating this and runs ,it is  always showing "Empty test suite" while running test and after finishing, it shows "No test were found".

Anybody knows how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally Got the solution(for project imported from eclipse):

Steps:

Create a folder named "androidTest" and inside that a new folder named "java" in your Module .Then in your build.gradle,add

```
androidTest.setRoot('androidTest')  instead of  

instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
```

Then run  "sync with gradle" .Now your "java" folder turns Green color(if it is not configured correctly ,then color will be red).

Then create your testcase java classes and test it .

Now My Structure is

```
"AppName/androidTest/java/FirstTest.java"
```

I hope this helps somebody ....

Comment: This saved my day..I wish the documentation had more info regarding the source sets while importing from eclipse

Comment: IMHO the better way to solve this would be to stick with the [maven Standard Directory Layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) as is is expected by gradle by default.

Answer (score -1):

project explorer in left, click project name. click right mouse button (option menu) -> Click "Open Module Settings" -> Click "Dependencies" tab -> Click "+" on your right side -> Click "Library dependecy" -> type "Junit" and search and go ahead

Comment: from the question you can see that the JUnit framework is correctly configured, terefor your post doeas not answer the question.